# Pointing out the mobile optimized page in desktop version(html)

Tags: html, http, seo, googlebot

I have a page `foo.bar/root` which is designed and optimzied for desktop devices, now I like to tell the search engines that `m.foo.bar/m-root` is the same page but optimized for mobile devices, how may I do this?
What kind of tag(or http header) shall I add to my responses to tell the dear Google index the mobile optimized page too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`alternate` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate) "creates a hyperlink referencing an alternate representation of the current document". With the `link` element, it could look like:

```html
<!-- on the desktop page <http://example.com/foo/> -->
<link href="http://m.example.com/foo/" rel="alternate">
```

You could also use the [`media` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-media) to specify "which media the resource applies to" (adjust the media query to your liking):

```html
<!-- on the desktop page <http://example.com/foo/> -->
<link href="http://m.example.com/foo/" rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)">
```

This is the plain HTML5 way.

According to [Google’s documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en), Google seems to recognize this markup, too.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much sir, but according to the `rel="alternate"` is used for pointing out the alternative page of the current one(usually different language), I really didn't find and know the `media` attr sir, thank you so much.